# The HTML code I scrape seems to be incomplete in comparison to the full website. Could the HTML be changing dynamically?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am currently scraping a website for work to be able to sort the data locally, however when I do this the code seems to be incomplete, and I feel may be changing whilst I scroll on the website to add more content. Can this happen ? And if so, how can I ensure I am able to scrape the whole website for processing?

I only currently know some python and html for web scraping, looking into what other elements may be affecting this issue (javascript or ReactJS etc).

I am expecting to get a list of 50 names when scraping the website, but it only returns 13. I have downloaded the whole HTML file to go through it and none of the other names seem to exist in the file, i.e. why I think the file may be changing dynamically

Comment: Sites practice lazy loading all of the time. The site loads with minimal information and makes calls via AJAX to load other content after the 'above the fold' content has been placed. Perhaps you can find the API calls and scrape those. There are javascript libraries like ScrollRevealjs that affect pages on-scroll.

Comment: Worth including your code and the website URL

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the content of the HTML can be dynamic, and Javascript loading should be the most essential . For Python, scrapy+splash maybe a good choice to get started.

Depending on how the data is handled, you can have different methods to handle dyamic content HTML